# How to make floating div responsive

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design, floating

I have a register page coded in a floating div. However, it does not load perfectly in responsive manner. I want to make a fixed height to ensure that when user view in different devices, the background color *#ebebeb* will be fixed. Unfortunately, it makes no different when i tried to change the % of height.

[image]

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/Snurainiyakob/V4u5X/892/

**css**

```
.modaloverlay .regmodal {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

@media (min-width: 60em) {
  .modaloverlay .regmodal {
    height: 87%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    max-height: 57em;
    max-width: 66em;
    width: 29%;
  }
}

.modaloverlay .regmodal > iframe, .modaloverlay .regmodal > div {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you show the html and css in a fiddle ? or can you give a url of the webpage

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Snurainiyakob/V4u5X/892/ similarly like this

Comment: it may be a problem with the popup you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `overflow:hidden` to wrapper all elements inside

**CSS**

```
.modaloverlay .regmodal {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: does not work in responsive as i unable to scroll down the form

Comment: it´s working (chrome, firefox)... the background of the modal  contain all elements inside even responsive... can you specified a little better your problem

Comment: I added more elements in the forms and when i load, the backgroud when i make it responsive it didn't cover the whole form like the photo example I uploaded.

Comment: Sorry, but i can´t see your problem...everything is working fine...like your jsfiddle...the modal background cover all elements... try overflow: auto, it´s shows scroll when needed.

Comment: then I'm not sure about it too.. It can be scrolled as i added `overflow: auto;` but the background color just not displaying correctly in terms of the height when i make it responsive....

Comment: You have some css (maybe media queries) that is affecting the responsive way...check all your css and see if there this some 'min-height' or 'height' in your modal

Comment: Hi. Do you mind help me out with this? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/922/) How should i make the height and width fixed such that when the word gets longer....

Comment: You can use overflow:hiden on your text container, set min-height or height and if the text is longer, use ellipsis - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Thanks! how about based on the codes i added above, how to make the font size smaller when the word is too long?

Comment: It´s not good make the font smaller...it´s a ui/Ux mistake... just hide the text with ellipsis, but on that div set on HTML the title tag with the full text

Comment: it's quite hard to  figure out what you stated here. but i have update it in fiddle. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/923/) it makes no different. I would like such the the div is same width and height no matter how long the text is. any solution for this? since you say making the font smaller is no good.

Comment: Please make a new question on stackoveflow...meanwhile is a jsfiddle -https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/V4u5X/924/

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot without knowing your layout, but have you looked into using viewport height? The height of an element is automatically proportional to the viewport of the device a user is on:

```
.element {
   height: 75vh;
}
```

The above would essentially ensure that `.element` is 75% height of whatever device's viewport is. Similarly, you can also use `vw` to achieve the same for viewport widths.